# get JSON Parse special column react native

Tags: json, react-native

I am pulling data from a link with fetc. But I don't know how to pull the data inside the date arm inside times. So I want to pull the array inside the date 2023-10-29. How can I do that?

JSON Output

```
{
    "place": {
        "country": "Turkey",
        "countryCode": "TR",
        "city": "Ankara",
        "region": "Ankara",
        "latitude": 39.91987,
        "longitude": 32.85427
    },
    "times": {
        "2023-10-29": [
            "05:42",
            "07:07",
            "12:37",
            "15:29",
            "17:58",
            "19:16"
        ]
    }
}
```

React Native Code

```
export function getData(lat,long,date,Key){
    return fetch(`https://n...`,{
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization':`Bearer ${Key}`        
        }
    })
}

   let rsp = await getData(lat,long,testDateUtc)
    rsp = await rsp.json()

  => console.log("here",rsp.times."2023-10-29")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation instead of dot notation.

```
rsp.times['2023-10-29']
```

See for [Accessing properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#accessing_properties) for details.